# How to open new file in split tab in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In VSCode I do it like [Alt + Mouse_Click] in Project Window - usefull, yea?
In IDEA - no idea )))

PS. Pls don't tell me to open file in existed split, then split it, and then close it in original split )

Comment: please upvote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226680

Comment: They deleted the topic after my comment )))) omg